# How to find the longest word in a given string?

Tags: java, string

In a given string, I want to **find the longest word** then print it in the console.

The output I get is the second longest word i.e `"Today"`, but I should get `"Happiest"` instead.
May I know what I am doing wrong? Is there a better/different way to find the longest word in a string?

```
public class DemoString {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s = "Today is the happiest day of my life";
        String[] word = s.split(" ");
        String longword = " ";
        for (int i = 0; i < word.length; i++)
            for (int j = 1 + i; j < word.length; j++)
                if (word[i].length() >= word[j].length())
                    longword = word[i];

        System.out.println(longword + " is the longest word with " + longword.length() + " characters.");
        System.out.println(rts.length());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 9):

Here is a "one-liner" you can use with the Java 8 streams API:

```java
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Comparator;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s = "Today is the happiest day of my life";
        String longest = Arrays.stream(s.split(" "))
                .max(Comparator.comparingInt(String::length))
                .orElse(null);
        System.out.println(longest);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
happiest
```

Try it out [**here**](https://onecompiler.com/java/3xvap9p65).

Comment: The link is asking for signup :(

Comment: Fixed the link to a site that doesn't require signup.  
Although I would still recommend signing up to https://repl.it since it is a great site.

Answer (score 5):

instead it should be:

```
for(int i=0; i < word.length; i++)
{
    if(word[i].length() >= rts.length())
    {
        rts = word[i];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

// the below Java Program will find Smallest and  Largest Word in a String

```
class SmallestAndLargestWord 
{ 

    static String minWord = "", maxWord = ""; 

    static void minMaxLengthWords(String input)  
    { 
        // minWord and maxWord are received by reference  
        // and not by value 
        // will be used to store and return output 
        int len = input.length(); 
        int si = 0, ei = 0; 
        int min_length = len, min_start_index = 0, 
              max_length = 0, max_start_index = 0; 

        // Loop while input string is not empty 
        while (ei <= len)  
        { 
            if (ei < len && input.charAt(ei) != ' ') 
            { 
                ei++; 
            }  
            else
            { 
                // end of a word 
                // find curr word length 
                int curr_length = ei - si; 

                if (curr_length < min_length)  
                { 
                    min_length = curr_length; 
                    min_start_index = si; 
                } 

                if (curr_length > max_length)  
                { 
                    max_length = curr_length; 
                    max_start_index = si; 
                } 
                ei++; 
                si = ei; 
            } 
        } 

        // store minimum and maximum length words 
        minWord = input.substring(min_start_index, min_start_index + min_length); 
        maxWord = input.substring(max_start_index, max_length); 
    } 

    // Driver code 
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    { 
        String a = "GeeksforGeeks A Computer Science portal for Geeks"; 

        minMaxLengthWords(a); 

        // to take input in string use getline(cin, a); 
        System.out.print("Minimum length word: "
                + minWord 
                + "\nMaximum length word: "
                + maxWord); 
    } 
}
```

**

```
Input : "GeeksforGeeks A computer Science portal for Geeks"
Output : Minimum length word: A
         Maximum length word: GeeksforGeeks
```

**

Answer (score 4):

```
    String s= "Today is the happiest day of my life by vijayakumar";
           String [] word = s.split(" ");
    String maxlethWord = "";
    for(int i = 0; i < word.length; i++){
            if(word[i].length() >= maxlethWord.length()){
                  maxlethWord = word[i];
            } 
    }
     System.out.println(maxlethWord);
```

Answer (score 3):

I haven't seen an answer where you create a list of the words.
So here is another way to solve the problem:

```
String s = "Today is the happiest day of my life";;
List<String> strings = Arrays.asList(s.split(" "));    
String biggestWord = Collections.max(strings, Comparator.comparing(String::length));
System.out.println(biggestWord);
```

Output:

```
happiest
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try like ,

```
  String s="Today is the happiest day of my life";
  String[] word=s.split(" ");
  String rts=" ";
  for(int i=0;i<word.length;i++){
     if(word[i].length()>=rts.length()){
       rts=word[i];
     }
  }
  System.out.println(rts);
  System.out.println(rts.length());
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one.

```
   public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        String s = "Today is the happiest day of my life";
        String[] word = s.split( " " );
        String rts = " ";

        for ( int i = 0; i < word.length; i++ )
        {
            if ( word[i].length() > rts.length() )
                rts = word[i];

        }
        System.out.println( rts );
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the below dart program to find the largest word in the string.
For example, if the input is "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog", the output should be "jumps".

```
void main() {
  print(findLongestWord('The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog'));
}

findLongestWord(String input) {
  int length = 0;
  int tempLength = 0;
  int index = 0;

  for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
    if (input[i] != ' ') {
      tempLength++;
    } else {
      if (tempLength >= length) {
        length = tempLength;
        index = i - length;
      }
      tempLength = 0;
    }
  }

   return input.substring(index, index + length);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
for(int i=0;i<word.length;i++){
            for(int j=0;j<word.length;j++){
                if(word[i].length()>=word[j].length()){
                   if(word[j].length()>=rts.length()) {
                      rts=word[j];
                   }
                } else if(word[i].length()>=rts.length()){
                   rts=word[i];
                }

            }
        }
```